# Magento JQuery Issue: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, paypal

I have installed an extension for paypal express checkout and the support is poor.

Here is the code and the errors.

```
$ipnpaypal = jQuery.noConflict();
$ipnpaypal(function(){
$ipnpaypal('a#ipnpaypalss').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // show loader on button click
    $ipnpaypal('.ajaxLoader').show();
    var productName     = $ipnpaypal(prodNameVal).html();
    var qty             = $ipnpaypal(qtyVal).val();
    var productTitle    = ("Order - " + qty + "x " + productName + www.demo.paketnik.si/magento_16 - PayPal");
    var sku             = $ipnpaypal(skuVal).attr("rel");
    var priceInclDdv    = $ipnpaypal(vatPriceVal).html();               
    priceInclDdv        = priceInclDdv.replace(',','.');
    priceInclDdv        = priceInclDdv.replace(/[^\d.]/g,'');
    var priceTotal      = parseFloat(priceInclDdv * qty);
    var returnUrl       = escape(jsReturnUrlVal);

    $ipnpaypal("form#paypalForm input#orderPackageName").val(productTitle);
    $ipnpaypal("form#paypalForm input#itemNumber").val(sku);
    $ipnpaypal("form#paypalForm input#paypal_amount").val(priceTotal);
    $ipnpaypal('#paypalForm').submit();
    });
});
```

Errors:

event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null

I have been told it's a jquery issue but I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried putting check for null on string before calling replace method on it as it says in error?

Comment: and check value of `priceInclDdv`

Comment: Please add your jquery code at the bottom of page.

Comment: What do you get from `$ipnpaypal(vatPriceVal).html();`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I haven't put a check for null in yet. The ipn paypal variable is for sending the price of a product plus its vat to paypal for processing. Magento User what JQuery code do you mean? I am using jQuery 1.10.2